# How to deploy a WAR to Jetty by copying to $JETTY_HOME/webapps?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, war, httpserver

Having installed Jetty, it's certainly running as I get a welcome page.

How do I [manually](https://docs.huihoo.com/jetty/the-definitive-reference/quickstart-deploying-webapps.html) deploy a `WAR` to Jetty?

> If you have a standard web application, you can hot deploy it into
> Jetty by copying it into the webapps directory.

Where is the webapps directory?  Or, how do I find the directory?

See [also](https://www.baeldung.com/deploy-to-jetty):

> 4. Deploying by Copying WAR
>
> The easiest way to deploy a web application to Jetty server is
> probably by copying the WAR file into the $JETTY_HOME/webapps
> directory.

output from `dpkg -L jetty9` as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/NICKSAUNDERS/b34f66eae68dcc08f9d4bae9915e067a) shows:

```
/usr/share/jetty9/logs
/usr/share/jetty9/start.d
/usr/share/jetty9/start.ini
/usr/share/jetty9/start.jar
/usr/share/jetty9/webapps
```

and:

```
/var/cache/jetty9
/var/lib
/var/lib/jetty9
/var/lib/jetty9/webapps
/var/lib/jetty9/webapps/README.TXT
/var/log
/var/log/jetty9
/usr/share/doc/jetty9/README.Debian
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas. $JETTY_HOME is a directory, to which you've installed (or unpacked) Jetty.

Comment: yes @greenmarker -- but where does apt install to?  that's the question.. I didn't "install" Jetty beyond typing "install jetty" if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu Jetty by default webapps directory is `/var/lib/jetty/webapps`.

To be sure, please check list of installed files (and to which directories they have been copied):

```
dpkg -L jetty
```

Comment: notion being that dropping a `WAR` into `/var/lib/jetty9/webapps` deploys the app?

Comment: Yes. It's done by Jetty's "deployment scanner". You can see it in Jetty logs. Once Jetty has started, in logs there's line like: 'Starting scanner at interval of 3 seconds'. When you put appName.war into /var/lib/jetty9/webapps, Jetty will notice it, you'll see in logs what happens during deployment and if it's successfull, your app should be visible under URL: http://localhost:8080/appName