# ERROR: Oops! Jetty doesn't appear to be installed

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, war, httpserver

Specific error:

```
** ERROR: Oops! Jetty doesn't appear to be installed in /home/nicholas
```

when trying `/usr/share/jetty9/bin/jetty.sh restart` from the console.

I, for one, wouldn't expect `apt` to install `Jetty` to `home`, so that's fine so far as it goes.  Clearly there's a misconfiguration or I'm not starting it properly.

trying to start `jetty`:

```
nicholas@tech:~$ 
nicholas@tech:~$ /usr/share/jetty9/bin/jetty.sh restart
/usr/share/jetty9/bin/jetty.sh: line 250: cd: /opt/jetty9: No such file or directory
** ERROR: Oops! Jetty doesn't appear to be installed in /home/nicholas
** ERROR:  /home/nicholas/start.jar is not readable!
nicholas@tech:~$
```

cat output of `/etc/default/jetty9`:

```
# change to 'no' or uncomment to use the default setting in /etc/default/rcS 
VERBOSE=yes

# Run Jetty as this user ID (default: jetty)
# Set this to an empty string to prevent Jetty from starting automatically
#JETTY_USER=jetty

# The home directory of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). You need at least
# Java 8. If JAVA_HOME is not set, some common directories for OpenJDK and
# the Oracle JDK are tried.
#JAVA_HOME=

# Extra options to pass to the JVM
#JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

# Timeout in seconds for the shutdown of all webapps
#JETTY_SHUTDOWN=30

# Additional arguments to pass to Jetty
#JETTY_ARGS=

# Jetty uses a directory to store temporary files like unpacked webapps
#JETTY_TMP=/var/cache/jetty9

# Default for number of days to keep old log files in /var/log/jetty9/
#LOGFILE_DAYS=14

# If you run Jetty on port numbers that are all higher than 1023, then you
# do not need authbind. It is used for binding Jetty to lower port numbers.
# (yes/no, default: no)
#AUTHBIND=yes



JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty9
JETTY_USER=jetty9
JETTY_PORT=8080
#JETTY_HOST=<span style="color: #ff0000;">127.0.0.1</span>
JETTY_LOGS=/opt/jetty9/logs/
```

I added the last few lines as [suggested](https://www.linuxcloudvps.com/blog/how-to-install-jetty-9-on-ubuntu-16-04/).

Jetty was [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62509854/4531180) using `apt` on Ubuntu.

Comment: The advice in the list you have given was about creating a *separate* configuration file, not about adding information to your script file. Also, if it is installed by apt, you should *not* meddle with its configuration. It is probably not installed in `/opt`, which doing `dpkg -L` would have shown you. Be carefull to fully read articles.

Comment: How is Jetty started, then, when it's installed via `apt`?  I ask because JETTY_HOME was not set when it was installed.

Comment: From the list of files, it looks like it starts automatically as a service. I would suggest searching for answers at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) (please read their help pages before asking a question), about starting and stopping services in general and adding wars to jetty in particular.

Comment: I commented out the lines I added and ran `sudo service jetty9 start` -- it's just odd because there's no JETTY_HOME anyhow...working.  thx.

Comment: Also, don't change contents in `JETTY_HOME`, treat it as read-only.  You are supposed to use the `JETTY_BASE` directory which is where your instance configuration is.  See output of `sudo service jetty9 status` (that should dump the important env variable for Jetty) to see where your `JETTY_BASE` directory is located.